# GlassFish Configuration Failed

Tags: installation, windows-server-2012-r2, glassfish

I just downloaded the installer and ran the typical one for glassFish 3.1, However I have tried 2 times now and have got the same error twice now any help would be greatly appreciated(I have searched on line and everything I found was install this version of Java (all different) and that didn't help)

the error is

```
PERFORMING THE REQUIRED CONFIGURATIONS
______________________________________

CREATING DOMAIN
_______________
Executing command :C:\glassfish3\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat --user admin --passwordfile C:\Users\cirrus\AppData\Local\Temp\2\glassfish-3.1-windows.exe5\asadminTmp4333077090323830119.tmp create-domain --savelogin --checkports=false --adminport 4848 --instanceport 8080 --domainproperties=jms.port=7676:domain.jmxPort=8686:orb.listener.port=3700:http.ssl.port=8181:orb.ssl.port=3820:orb.mutualauth.port=3920 domain1
C:\glassfish3\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat --user admin --passwordfile C:\Users\cirrus\AppData\Local\Temp\2\glassfish-3.1-windows.exe5\asadminTmp2688890700362893572.tmp create-domain --savelogin --checkports=false --adminport 4848 --instanceport 8080 --domainproperties=jms.port=7676:domain.jmxPort=8686:orb.listener.port=3700:http.ssl.port=8181:orb.ssl.port=3820:orb.mutualauth.port=3920 domain1The system cannot find the path specified.
```

the message above the error is

```
The configuration has failed. Please see the output below.
```

I'm trying to install on a virtual that run windows server 2012R2

Answer (score 0):

Looks error is:

> The system cannot find the path specified

Not clear what file is missing from output provided.

My suggestion is to use Process Monitor https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx to find what file installer looking for during setup. Start with 2 filters:

- Result is not success
- Process Name contains "whatever_name_of_your_installer_is.exe"

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than running the installer, you could just download the zip distribution and extract to a location of your choice. All the installer really does on top of that is to verify that you have the correct Java and that it's configured properly. If you are happy with your configuration of Java (or can set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable correctly), then there is nothing wrong with using the zip distribution. It may not be a solution, but it could be an acceptable workaround for you.